# Lista dináminca: error "ReferenceError: list is not defined", crea `<li>` sólo si antes borro `<li>` que no esta creado

Tags: javascript

Quiero crear una lista dinámica, pero me encuentro con que al pulsar el botón de crear `<li>` me sale el siguiente error `"ReferenceError: list is not defined"`.

Pero si pulso el primero un botón de borrar y luego de crear si me va creando `<li>` cada vez que pulso, tal y como lo quiero conseguir.

pero no soy capaz de ver donde tengo el fallo por el que me sale error de primeras.
Os dejo el código para que hechéis un vistazo a como lo hago y el resultado que me sale al ejecutarse.

```js
 window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById('botones').addEventListener("click",cargarBotones,true);
 };

 function cargarBotones(){
     var botones = "<button id='crear' >Crea li</button><br><br>"+
     "<button id='borraIni' >borrar primer li</button><br><br>"+
     "<button id='borraFin' >borra ultimo li</button><br><br>";

     var body = document.body;
     var list = document.createElement("ul");
     body.appendChild(list);
     document.getElementById("boton").innerHTML = botones;
     document.getElementById("crear").addEventListener("click",crearLi,true);
     document.getElementById("borraIni").addEventListener("click",borrarIni,true);
     document.getElementById("borraFin").addEventListener("click",borrarFin,true);
 }


var listado = ['Alaves', 'Athletic Club', 'Atletico de Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Celta de Vigo', 'Eibar', 'Espanyol', 'Getafe', 'Girona', 'Huesca', 'Leganés', 'Levante', 'Rayo Vallecano', 'Real Betis', 'Real Madrid', 'Real Sociedad', 'Real Valladolid', 'Sevilla', 'Valencia', 'Villarreal'];

function crearLi() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    for (var j = 0; j < listado.length; j++) {
        li.innerHTML = listado[parseInt(Math.random() * listado.length)];
    }
    list.appendChild(li);
}

function borrarIni() {
    list = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
}

function borrarFin() {
    list = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
    list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <button id="botones" >Cargar botones</button><br><br>
      <div id="boton"></div>
      <div id="lista"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como dice @Alvaro Sanchez, estas intentando usar las mismas variables en diferentes funciones, para ello debes definirías como globales y esto lo haces creándolas fuera del ámbito de cualquier función

He modificado tu código para indicarte como hacer

```js
document.getElementById('botones').addEventListener("click",cargarBotones,true);

var body = document.body,
 list = document.createElement("ul"),
 listado = ['Alaves', 'Athletic Club', 'Atletico de Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Celta de Vigo', 'Eibar', 'Espanyol', 'Getafe', 'Girona', 'Huesca', 'Leganés', 'Levante', 'Rayo Vallecano', 'Real Betis', 'Real Madrid', 'Real Sociedad', 'Real Valladolid', 'Sevilla', 'Valencia', 'Villarreal'];

 function cargarBotones(){
     var botones = "<button id='crear' >Crea li</button><br><br>"+
     "<button id='borraIni' >borrar primer li</button><br><br>"+
     "<button id='borraFin' >borra ultimo li</button><br><br>";

     body.appendChild(list);
     document.getElementById("boton").innerHTML = botones;
     document.getElementById("crear").addEventListener("click",crearLi,true);
     document.getElementById("borraIni").addEventListener("click",borrarIni,true);
     document.getElementById("borraFin").addEventListener("click",borrarFin,true);
 }



function crearLi() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    for (var j = 0; j < listado.length; j++) {
        li.innerHTML = listado[parseInt(Math.random() * listado.length)];
    }
    list.appendChild(li);
}

function borrarIni() {
    list = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
}

function borrarFin() {
    list = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
    list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <button id="botones" >Cargar botones</button><br><br>
      <div id="boton"></div>
      <div id="lista"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema a simple vista que list esta encapsulada en la función cargarBotones prueba en quitar la palabra reservada "var" a la variable list, esta es la unica manera de crear variables globales en JavaScript o prueba en poner esta sentencia var list = document.createElement("ul"); arriba de la función cargarBotones